# Start fullscreen activity when the app starts - UniversalMusicPlayer

Tags: android, android-activity, android-music-player

I am going to make an online radio app with the help of [UniversalMusicPlayer Google Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer). I manage to skip genre and album list and show direct track in MusicPlayerActivity by modifying MusicProvider class:

```
if (MEDIA_ID_ROOT.equals(mediaId)) {
        mediaItems.add(createBrowsableMediaItemForRoot(resources));
}
```

to

```
if (MEDIA_ID_ROOT.equals(mediaId)) {
        mediaItems.add(createMediaItem(buildRadioTrack()));
}

private MediaMetadataCompat buildRadioAamarTrack() {
    //noinspection ResourceType
    return new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder()
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_MEDIA_ID, id)
            .putString(MusicProviderSource.CUSTOM_METADATA_TRACK_SOURCE, source)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM, album)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, artist)
            .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, duration)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_GENRE, genre)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, iconUrl)
            .putString(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, title)
            .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_TRACK_NUMBER, trackNumber)
            .putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_NUM_TRACKS, totalTrackCount)
            .build();
}
```

Now I want to skip MusicPlayerActivity and show FullScreenPlayerActivity with my radio track (as this is my only track). Cannot figure out what to do. Can you please help me with this issue?

Comment: Can you be a lil more specific please? Whats the actual issue/requirement?

Comment: Dear @Suhayl, this is a [project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer) specific question. It is a media player sample which first presents a list of genre, after clicking genre, album list is shown and then track list from selected album. after selecting track it plays. If you touch bottom play area in that activity, it goes fullscreen which I am concerned about. I want to start the app direct to fullscreen as my app has only one track.